# Setting up Wordpress Locally on WAMP for a new site (with one already)

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, windows

Here are the steps I took in downloading and setting up WordPress on a WAMP (Windows, Apache2, MySQL, PHP):

1.) Download WAMP Server, here: [WAMP Server Installation](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/)

2.) Download [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/) on Wordpress.org

3.) Using PHP MyAdmin, click on Databases, and 'create new database' (choose a name)

4.) Extract the downloaded zip Wordpress file and copy it to C:/WAMP/www/ and paste WordPress folder there

http://localhost/wordpress  and it works!

5.) Create a confif.php file and add the database name that you created above

6.) Follow the instructions on screen to install WordPress and then login

That's it! Everything looks great and I can customize my Wordpress Site on localhost/wordpress - The name of my wordpress folder

Now, I am done with my first site and I would like to create another site. My quesiton is:

Do I have to go through this process again? Do I use the same database created to create another site which will have different content? If so, how can I do this? What steps do I follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, usually you create a new database, user and password as well as use another copy of WordPress to create a new site. You can create a new directory in the same place where the "wordpress" directory is located and use that one for the new site.

Note that it is possible to use the same database for two different sites if you use a different table prefix (usually wp_). However, this is only advisable in same cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to create new database for new wordpress site. It's imposible to create several wordpress websites with one database if you use prefix in tables names.

Comment: Along with the new database, you also need a new set of WP files in a separate folder. Each site is accessed via it's subfolder. You might want to put both sites in a subfolder, so it will show up as https://localsite/site1 and https://localsite/site2 to keep things separate and easy to differentiate.